# NavigationDrawer RecyclerView change selected item style

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

I am trying to change the textColor in my NavigationDrawer when item is selected.I am using RecyclerView as my swipe layout. This is based on the tutorial: http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html.
this is what I am trying to do:
[image: NavigationDrawerStyle]
This is the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
            android:elevation="7sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the list_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:paddingTop="8dp"
              android:paddingBottom="8dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#ffffff"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rowIcon"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/rowText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I tell him to change the color when it's selected?

Comment: I have a question,Do you really need to use RecyclerView?considering that you have 10 items at the max?in a navigation drawer?

Comment: Yeah,  I backed to ListView

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add a variable to remember the selected position.
Then add a click listener on your item list. 
When item list clicked, check if the position is the same as previous selected position, if not then change it style and reset the style of previous selected item.

From the tutorial you used, you can set the listener inside method **onCreateViewHolder**

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false);
ViewHolder vhItem = new ViewHolder(v,viewType);
TextView textView = (TextView) vhItem.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //change style here
                }
            }););
```

Comment: Well actually this works except is quite mechanic solution while on ListView you can easily set the background style of the item_template when it's selected

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onClick method in adapter class which extends from RecyclerView.Adapter<> inside onBindViewHolder method like below code and apply your logic to change the color according to selected item position

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final Quizviewholder holder, int position) {
            holder.quizname.setText(quizList.get(position).name);
            holder.desc.setText(quizList.get(position).desc);
            holder.time.setText(quizList.get(position).quttime);
            holder.noofque.setText(quizList.get(position).qutonsno);
            holder.setClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    if (isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Rj0078" + position + " - " + mList[position] + " (Long click)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Rj0078" + position + " - " + holder.time.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```